# Auto resizing a row based on an angle word size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a HTML table and I want my heading to be rotated 45 degrees.

I have found a few examples on the web which I can use.
However the header row height does not resize to the text entered. The text just wraps in the cell.

How do I make the row auto adjust the cell height according to the angled text?

My Code

HTML

```
  <div class="scrollable-table">
    <table class="table table-striped table-header-rotated">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
          <th></th>
          <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
          <th class="column criterion rotate-45" ><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
          <th class="column criterion rotate-45" ><div><span>Column header 2</span></div></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
          <td><input checked="checked" name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column1"></td>
          <td><input checked="checked" name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row1-column2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header">Row header 2</th>
          <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row2-column1"></td>
          <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header">Row header 3</th>
          <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row3-column1"></td>
          <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row3-column2"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.table-header-rotated th.row-header{
  width: auto;
}

.table-header-rotated td{
  width: 40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45{
  height: 80px;
  width: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0.8;
}

.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45 div{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 40px; /* 80 * tan(45) / 2 = 40 where 80 is the height on the cell and 45 is the transform angle*/
  height: 100%;
  -ms-transform:skew(-45deg,0deg);
  -webkit-transform:skew(-45deg,0deg);
  transform:skew(-45deg,0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45 span {
  -ms-transform:skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  -webkit-transform:skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  transform:skew(45deg,0deg) rotate(315deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px; /* 40 cos(45) = 28 with an additional 2px margin*/
  left: -25px; /*Because it looked good, but there is probably a mathematical link here as well*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px; /* 80 / cos(45) - 40 cos (45) = 85 where 80 is the height of the cell, 40 the width of the cell and 45 the transform angle*/
  text-align: left;
  /* white-space: nowrap; *//*whether to display in one line or not*/
}
```

please see
http://jsfiddle.net/ephreal/9kxd3chm/

**EDIT**
I made a solution which is based on Jquery.
I calculate the row height based on the pixle length of the text string. 
A few other values i found could just be left static in my case. Please see my
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ephreal/o44u1fpp/21/)

Regards

Comment: I see border on divs ... not too clear, is this kind of what you look for ? http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/EvCHi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add **white-space:nowrap;** to your header style

```
.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45 {
    height: 80px;
    width: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvucgfmk/1/

Comment: Hmm it does not change the size of the row depended on the size of the text which is really what i wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/ephreal/nvucgfmk/2/

Comment: Because you said, that the text just wraps in the cell I assumed, that this is your actual problem. You might need to use a different method to get what you want.
Have you tried this: https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

The result looks identical, but the css is different and after a quick test with dev-tools at least the headers cells are adjusting to the text, just not the header row. Maybe that is enough for you.

Comment: Sorry that it was unclear however my question was the single paragraph **How do I make the row auto adjust the cell height according to the angled text?**

Comment: The link your linked to is the one with the example I'm using. they also have fixed height.